# Can I run a c program in Ubuntu without using gcc?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, terminal

Am using an online compiler..when I am trying to execute a c program using gcc which is not found its showing error.I can't install it too as it is asking for psw..what are the other ways to execute a c prog ?

I tried giving gcc filename.c...it showed command gcc not found but can be installed with..since I used a online compiler...I couldn't install anything without the psw.

Comment: You can't run a C program without a compiler.  It doesn't have to be gcc, there are other choices, but gcc is probably the most popular.  I'm surprised you can't find a way to install it without requiring a password.